# Linear Systems: Exponentials of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a rather odd question to some, but one that has stumped me for a good few minutes on a homework assignment that states:

> > For each matrix, find the eigenvalues of $\text{exp}{(A)}$, where $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix.

When it ask to find the eigenvalues, does it mean to find the eigenvalues of $A$ or to literally find the eigenvalues of $\text{exp}(A)$?

Comment: For any analytical function $f$, what is the relationship between eigenspaces and eigenvalues of $A$ and $f(A)$?

Comment: It means expressing the  eigenvalues of $\exp A$ with the eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: @Bernard, could you clarify what that means?

Comment: $exp(x) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ / 

Usually $x\in\mathbb{R}$, but sometimes nasty $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$

/ And you are asked to compute the eigenvalues of this case in terms of the eigenvalues of the original matrix

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint: Let $(\lambda,x)$ be an eigenpair of $A$ and consider

$$
\exp(A)x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{A^n x}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^n x}{n!}
$$